# How do I create a Ruby script that can generate an infinite number of unique URLs ie. myurl.com/1, myurl.com/2 etc…?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it also possible to specify what comes after the "/" to some extent? For example, have every URL be myurl.com/hello and then append a number to the end so that it is unique?

Comment: Use a database table with an auto-incrementing id or a uuid function which generates hashes with a low chance of collision.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you an idea?

```
last_url = "myurl.com/hello0"
10.times{ puts last_url.succ! }
```

Comment: Yes this helps. Much appreciated.